# How to prevent sort indicator overlap border in ng-table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When we load `ng-table` on `IE/Edge`, the sort indicator on angular table overlap border as below, but it works well on `google chrome`.
The problem is position of sort indicator, it's set relative. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try http://caniuse.com/ to diagnose any really basic compatibility issues.

Comment: Argh...IE is the bane of web developers. You may have to use IE-specific CSS.